# Why does adding a tab in PySimpleGUI change the size of the old tab's vertical size?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an app, which allows you to view images, and when you click on the browse button, you can browse files (.png, .jpg, and .jpeg), but when I do, it creates a new tab, in my tab group. However, I notice that when I do this, the main tab's content, is now larger, in the vertical direction. I have tried to debug, looking for key mismatches etc, but it doen't seem to help.

Complete Code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import os, os.path
from PIL import Image
ly = [
    [sg.In("Add File", (20, 1), enable_events=True, key="-FILE-"),
    sg.FileBrowse(file_types=(("Image Files", "*.png"), ("Image Files", "*.jpg"), ("Image Files", "*.jpeg")))],
]
gl = [
    [sg.Tab("New File", ly, key="-NEW FILE-",title_color="#b8b8b8", background_color="#a3a3a3")],
]
tl = [
    [sg.TabGroup(gl, key="-TABS-", background_color="#bfbfbf", selected_background_color="#b8b8b8",tab_background_color="#c7c5c5",)]
]
layout = [
    [tl],
]
window = sg.Window("Image Viewer", layout, size=(250, 250), background_color="#d9d9d9", finalize=True, resizable=True)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "-FILE-":
        if os.path.isfile(values["-FILE-"]) and values["-FILE-"].endswith((".png", ".gif")):
            nt = sg.Tab(os.path.basename(values["-FILE-"]), [[sg.Image(values["-FILE-"])]])
            window["-TABS-"].add_tab(nt)
        elif os.path.isfile(values["-FILE-"]) and values["-FILE-"].endswith((".jpg", ".jpeg")):
            file = values["-FILE-"]
            file = Image.open(file).save(f"{file}.png", "PNG")
            nt = sg.Tab(os.path.basename(values["-FILE-"]), [[sg.Image(values["-FILE-"]+".png")]])
            window["-TABS-"].add_tab(nt)
            os.remove(values["-FILE-"]+".png")
window.close()
```

Note: I am new to PySimpleGUI and I may be missing something very obvious, so sorry if that's the case.

Comment: If nothing wrong, the size of tabgroup or tabs are kept the same all the time. After you add new tab with larger image, the size of main tab will be adjusted to be the same, but not viewed greater than the size of window you specified.

Comment: Oh thanks, so there is really no way to fix this... Thanks for letting me know!